# .NET REGEX Matching matches empty strings

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-4.0, match

I have this

pattern:

```
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*
```

Target:

```
X=113.3413475 Y=18.2054775
```

And i want to match the numbers. It matches find in testing software like http://regexpal.com/ and Regex Coach.

But in Dot net and http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

I get:

```
Found 11 matches:

1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.  113.3413475
7.
8.
9.
10. 18.2054775
11.

String literals for use in programs:

C#
    @"[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*"
```

Any one have any idea why i'm getting all these empty matches.

Thanks and Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that will match empty string. Look at it:

```
[0-9]* - zero or more digits
\.?    - an optional period
[0-9]* - zero or more digits
```

Everything's optional, so an empty string matches.

It sounds like you always want there to be digits *somewhere*, for example:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+
```

(The order here matters, as you want it to take the most possible.)

That works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = "X=113.3413475 Y=18.2054775";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]+\.[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+");
        var matches = regex.Matches(x);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
113.3413475
18.2054775
```

There may well be better ways of doing it, admittedly :)

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey: That would fail in cases such as "123", "123." or ".123" - all of which I believe the OP wants.

Comment: I see good catch. After running yours through my test, it works great. +1

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to keep your original regex, and just assert it must have a number in it (maybe after a dot):

```
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*
```

Goes to:

```
(?=\.?[0-9])[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

It's slightly different that Jon Skeet's answer in that it won't match `.45`, it requires either a number alone (e.g. `8`) or a real decimal (e.g. `8.1` or `0.1`)

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is the `*`, which means "match zero or more of the preceding characters". The empty string matches zero or more digits, which is why you're getting all those matches.

Change your two `*`s to `+`s and you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this regex is that it is completely optional in all the fields, so an empty string also is matched by it. I would consider adding all the cases. By the regex, I see you want the numbers with or without dot, and with or without a set of decimal digits. You can separate first those that contain only numbers `[0-9]+`, then those that contain numbers plus only a dot, `[0-9]+\.` and then join them all with `|` (or).

The problem with the regex as it is is that it allows cases that are not real numbers, for example, the cases in which the first set of numbers *and* the last set of numbers are empty (just a dot), so you have to put the valid cases explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex pattern = new Regex( @"[0-9]+[\.][0-9]+");

string info = "X=113.3413475 Y=18.2054775";

MatchCollection matches = pattern.Matches(info);

int count = 1;
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", count++, match.Value);
}

//output
//1 : 113.3413475
//2 : 18.2054775
```

Replace your * with + and remove ? from your period case.

EDIT: from above conversation: @"[0-9]+.[0-9]*|.[0-9]+|[0-9]+", is the better case. catches 123, .123, 123.123 etc

Comment: Wow guess I should have refreshed before posting..... :) yay what they said.

You can run my example in linqpad.