# C# Regex Replace and *

Tags: c#, perl

I'm a perl programmer doing a bit of C#.  Facing an odd issue with Regex.Replace in regard to the zero-or-more assertion, *.

Say I wanted to replace zero or more letters with a single letter.  In perl, I could do this:

```
my $s = "A";
$s =~ s/\w*/B/;
print $s;
$s now = "B"
```

But if I try and do the same in C#, like this:

```
string s = Regex.Replace("A", @"\w*", "B");
s now = "BB"
```

The docs do say "The * character is not recognized as a metacharacter within a replacement pattern"

Why?  And is there any work around if you want a bit of your regex to slurp up some left over string which may not be there (like ".*?" on the end)

(this is a silly example, but you get the point)

Comment: @rich.okelly, is it really matter?

Comment: Interesting, fyi: ^\w*$ works fine.

Comment: @ingenu has the answer - should work in Perl and C#. Interesting... Looks like a bug, as if it is treating the EOL as a separate matchable. (The replacement pattern is "B" so that's a red herring.)

Comment: @Ben I was merely answering why it was important.  However, as you brought it up - I did click through and thought at least two of those questions had acceptable / useful answers - even if caveats would need to be added to the comments.

Comment: This has to be a bug: this `Regex.Replace(".,A", @"\w*", "B")` becomes  `B.B,BB`

Comment: I don't have perl at hand to test but what would happen if your substitution was changed to `$s =~ s/Z*/B/;` It should be able to match zero Z characters both before and after the A and I'm intrigued if it does or does something else magic. Its related to my explanation of why C# does what it does...

Comment: @MattFellows, To me, the Apache one is marginal, the others a big No. However I am sure we can agree to disagree on whether the answers were acceptable -- and allow the asker the same privilege.

Comment: This is a really good question! To distill it down, the issue is: Why is `Regex.Matches("A", @"\w*").Count` equal to `2` rather than `1`? And although [a similar question has been asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326679/net-regex-matching-matches-empty-strings), for me the question of **why** is still open. After all, `"A"` is also 65 empty strings, followed by `A`, followed by 324 empty strings, so why **`2`** matches rather than `390` ?!

Comment: @MattFellows, I am sure he will accept a useful answer when he gets one.

Comment: @Ben based on his first comment - I do not have as much faith as you.

Comment: @MattFellows My apologies for not using the site "correctly" so to speak.  The reason I have never accepted any answer to any of my questions is more that I've never actually had an "answer".  Always a work around/it can't be done.  I've gone though and "accepted" anything that could be considered the answer to all my Q's

Comment: @didster Then my concerns are alleviated and I shall eat humble pie :D

Comment: @MattFellows It's OK!  Just explain why \w* matches "" at the end of the string when not anchored in C# but not in perl and we will call it quits ;o)

Comment: @didster - I'd guess that c# does it wrong to be honest - as it seems to iteratively process each character. 1st char matches so replaces, then it finds a zero length match afterwards and replaces that. Perl pretty much invented regex so I'd say that was the correct way...

Comment: @MattFellows this was really the source of my confusion.  All my regex experience comes from Perl and <anything>* will match zero or more of anything, by default being greedy. The comment in MSDN also confused me: "The * character is not recognized as a metacharacter within a replacement pattern"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your pattern with ^ and end it with $ and your problem is solved.

```
string s = Regex.Replace("AAAA", @"^\w*$", "B");
Console.Write(s);
```

Alternatively - you can stop matching on 0 length strings with the `+` operator instead of the `*` operator:

```
string s = Regex.Replace("AAAA", @"\w+", "B");
Console.Write(s);
```

Comment: Are you able to explain why this works out of interest? It does but I'm interested in why the observed behaviour in the original example and thus why you need to do this at all...

Comment: It seems `^\w*` is enough but I would very much like to know why.

Comment: @Ingenu: having asked the question myself just after you I think I answered it. :)

Comment: I would also like to know why!

Comment: @didster Some of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/q/9228096/460785 get quite close to explaining why.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Fellows has the right answer on how to fix it. I believe I can try to explain why it breaks like that though...

Consider this:

Regex.Replace("AAA", @"Z*", "!!!|$&|")

It will return:

```
!!!||A!!!||A!!!||A!!!||
```

Z* in this case will match a series of zero length strings, each one sitting before or after one of the A characters. The `$&` puts in the matched string which in this case we can see is empty.

A similar thing happens I believe with

```
Regex.Replace("AAA", @"A*", "!!!|$&|")
```

Which returns

```
!!!|AAA|!!!||
```

The A* matching starts at the beginning and matches "AAA". It then matches "" and then stops.

I'm not sure if this is desired behaviour in this case but I suspect it is a necessary side effect of the way A* matches zero length strings.

Of course when you change the pattern to `^A*$` then the anchoring means that there is only one possible match and does more like what is expected in this case.

Comment: Just came to the same conclusion myself while playing.  If you use `+`  (1 or more) rather than `*` (0 or more) that also solves the problem.

Comment: Yes indeed though of course the question becomes why `*` was used in the first place instead of `+`. There may have been a good reason that in the case that the string was empty for example it should be wanted to match.

Comment: Also if you want to edit your answer to reflect this information you are welcome. I do feel a bit like I may be ninjaing your answer since I'd not have got here without your initial observation. :)

Comment: Heh - I have put it the `+` vs `*` part into my answer but your answer is much more complete so will leave you with it ;)

Comment: Going to have to start a new thread soon - but why would `string s = Regex.Replace(".A.", @"\w*", "B");` give `B.BB.B` - it should wither be `B.BBB.B` or `B.B.B` shouldn't it?

Comment: Asking this question here now - see if I can get more visibility on it specifically http://stackoverflow.com/q/9228096/460785

Comment: The way to look at it is to consider each potential match to start at a character divide and go forwards munching up as much as it can. That should give you the right answer (as others on the other question have also indicated).