# Regex.Replace without line start and end terminators has some very strange effects.... What is going on here?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

While answering this question [C# Regex Replace and *](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9227438/460785) the point was raised as to why the problem exists.  When playing I produced the following code:

```
    string s = Regex.Replace(".A.", "\w*", "B");
    Console.Write(s);
```

This has the output: `B.BB.B`

I get that the 0 length string is match before and after the `.` character, but why is A replaced by 2 Bs.

I could understand `B.BBB.B` as replacing zero-length strings either side of `A` or `B.B.B`
But the actual result confuses me - any help appreciated.

Or as AakashM has put it:

Why is `Regex.Matches("A", "\w*").Count` equal to `2`, not `1` or `3` ?

Comment: I slightly prefer this formulation: "Why is `Regex.Matches("A", @"\w*").Count` equal to `2` rather than `1`", which I think is about as simply-posed as this question can be. I really hope we get a good answer from some luminary...

Comment: I think I can understand it equal to `3` as well - but yes that is a nicely succinct way to put it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because \w* is a greedy regex and it tries to find biggest sequence. So it matches `"nothing"` before dot, then `"nothing"A` between two dots then `"nothing"` before second dot and finally `"nothing"` after the second dot.

Comment: Between the dots it matches `A"nothing"`, when I inspect the MatchCollection.

Comment: In java it matches `"nothing"A`. I printed start indexes of matching groups and matched strings and the result was  
0  
1A  
2  
3

Comment: ... as a note to the op... "\w*?" would make it "lazy none-or-more" (aka "not greedy").  Similarly \w+ is greedy one-or-more and \w+? is lazy one-or-more and so on. What the OP probably wanted was `Regex.Replace(".A.", @"\w+?","B");` I hope that is helpful.

Comment: @Ademiban: Your output actually proves that Hans Kesting is correct.

Answer (score 12):

There is a star after \w

It means "**zero** or many" so that means:

- First symbol is a dot, it is NOT \w so there is **zero \w** here, replace by B
- Next we have a dot itself, which is not replaceable
- A gets replaced by B
- zero \w before the next dot, replace by B
- dot, not replaceable
- Line end, zero \w so replace by B again.

Expression `\w{0,}` will have the same effect.

If you want to avoid it, use 'plus' which means 'at least one': `\w+`

Comment: This is a conceptual, contrived, hypothetical question, not an actual problem. I think I understand what you are saying though...  In my string if I put a `|` in where there are 0 length matches it would look like: `|.A|.|` so replacing `|` with `B` and the 1 length match of `A` with `B` we get `B.BB.B`...

Comment: But why the match on the zero length `\w` just after the "real" match on the "A"? Why is that not included? When the string is ".ABC.", then there is a match on "ABC" and on the empty string after it. Why not on "AB"; empty string; "C"?

Comment: @HansKesting It is not included because dot is not \w. So it sees dot, it realizes that it is "zero \w" so it puts B in it.

Comment: @mesiesta What do you mean? I have explained the algorithm. It explains exactly WHY each symbol is on its place.

Comment: @HansKesting Why not on "AB"; empty string; "C"? Well, just because A, B and C are ALL \w. So they ALL fall into the \w* category which is (any number of alphabetical symbols). Dot is NOT in \w category so it stops on dot.

Comment: @AlexeyRaga To match my "ABC" the regex has to see that the `\w*` match stops at the '.'. I still don't see the need for an *extra* match on an empty string before that *same* dot that already ended the "ABC" match.

Comment: @HansKesting there is no ant _extra_ match. That "the same" dot is _not included_ in ABC. What you say "already ended" is not quite correct. It ended indeed, but it is not included and will be considered for future parsing. Imagine if you had an expression like "\w*\." It will find "ABC." _including_ dot. Just \w* will successfully find chars _up to_ dot, then will repeat parsing on the remaining of the string (starting with dot).

Answer (score 6):

Thats the same behaviour than

`Regex.Replace("", "\w*", "B")` results in B
`Regex.Replace("A", "\w*", "B")` results in BB

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vvls)

For the string ".A." `\w*` matches before the first dot the empty string, then on the "A", after the "A" the empty string and after the last dot the empty string.

**Explanation**

You can think of the pattern eating the characters, `\w*` has eaten the "A", the next char is a dot, so this match is complete and replaced. But the start position for the pattern to continue matching is still between the A and the dot. The dot can not be matched, so it matches the empty string before the dot, but then this position is done and the next start position is after the dot.

Answer (score 2):

By default it's greedy match, so it search's maximum of matches. There is why you get that result.

If you do with reluctant way, like this

```
string s = Regex.Replace(".A.", "\\w*?", "B");
```

You will get this result, because it finding minimum matches.

```
B.BAB.B
```

Comment: That almost makes sense now - why is the A not replaced too?

Comment: Yeah, I just have realized that it is really strange.