# Regex.Replace has strange behavior at reluctant match

Tags: c#, java, regex

Answering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228096/regex-replace-without-line-start-and-end-terminators-has-some-very-strange-effec/9228354#comment11621174_9228354) question I stuck with this situation. Using reluctant match in my regex bring to this result

```
string s = Regex.Replace(".A.", "\\w*?", "B");
```

> B.BAB.B

Why it doesn't match and replace A?

Comment: it's good policy to use the verbatim string, keeps the regex unchanged by System.String:  @"\w+?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `\\w*?` matches as few `\w` as it possibly can, **including 0 of them**.

Since you have `\w*` instead of `\w+`, the regex matches 0 or more `\w`.

Since you have an additional `?` on the `\w*`, the smallest possible match for this regex is the 0-length string, ''.

Since the `?` *forces* the regex to match as small a match as possible, it only *ever* matches 0-length strings. It can't match a single character `A` because that would be a longer match than the shortest.

Hence all 0-length strings in `.A.` (being: `''.''A''.''`, where each possible 0-length string is marked as `''`) are replaced with a 'B', giving you 'B.A.B'.

If you want to disable this behaviour and replace at least one `\w`, you can use regex `\w+?`. However, by the same reasoning as before, the `?` forces this to only ever replace `\w` of length one, so you may as well use regex `\w`.

Comment: Yes, seems it's really problem of indexes... It matches emptyness in 0 index, and switch to 1 index, where is also emptiness.